# Complex order statement with rails AREL: SQL Case statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I've got this bit of code that basically tries to use a SQL case  statement in the active relation order method:

```
relation = Foo.order("CASE WHEN foos.thing IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC")
```

and in the generated (and executed) SQL it comes up as:

```
(ORDER BY CASE ASC)
```

I've tried digging down into the source and lose the thread down in the visitor.access call. Is this a known issue? Is it user error? Is there some magical thing I have to do to make it happen? I was under the impression that it just inserted the raw SQL. There are other things we're doing with the relation, such as select, limit, offset, group, having and joins.

help! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had this problem too:

You can put the CASE into the SELECT and name it so you can use it in the ORDER BY.

```
relation = Foo.select("*, CASE WHEN foos.thing IS NOT 
  NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS foo_order").order("foo_order ASC")
```

Comment: This breaks when there's a join, like when you use .includes(...)

Comment: Maybe you need DISTINCT foos.* instead of just *